# React Router returns blank page

Tags: reactjs, router

I noticed that when trying to run my react app it simply returns a blank page, which I am guessing has to do with using router-dom lib. I have to use the router lib in order to redirect me to an authentication login page, are there any changes that would allow me to display  correctly?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App, {history} from './App'
import {
    auth0ClientId,
    auth0ProviderDomain
} from "./constants/environment";
import {AppState, Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const onRedirectCallback = (appState: AppState) => {
    // If using a Hash Router, you need to use window.history.replaceState to
    // remove the `code` and `state` query parameters from the callback url.
    // window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
    history.replace((appState && appState.returnTo) || window.location.pathname);
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Auth0Provider
            domain={auth0ProviderDomain}
            clientId={auth0ClientId}
            audience="urn:apigee:target:api"
            redirectUri={window.location.origin}
            connection="azuread"
            onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        >
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<App/>} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Auth0Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```